# Email Google Sheet cells and format

Tags: email, google-apps-script

**Background:** I am a teacher. I gave a test through Forms. I graded the test by using various background colors on each cell (which represented an answer to a question by a student). Each row of the sheet has their email address in Column B.

**Problem:** I would like to email the entire row, including formatting, to that address in Column B so that each student has a record of their answers and how I graded them.

**Question:** How can I email a row of data, including formatting?

I am working with the following script, which works well for emailing a single cell without formatting:

```
`function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1];  // Second column
    var message = row[0];       // I want the whole row, including formatting.
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    ContentService.createTextOutput("hello world!");
  }
}`
```

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Here it is.

I decided to add another function as it makes it a little cleaner.  You'll be able to adjust the styles of the output by playing with the css styles.  If you keep the commented lines your can use them for debugging.  I tested the code with them and it looks good.  So let me know how it works on the emails.

```
  function sendEmails() 
  {
  var br='<br />';
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  var dataRange=sheet.getDataRange();
  var dataA=dataRange.getValues();
  var backA=dataRange.getBackgrounds();
  //var s='';//Please leave the commented lines.  If needed for the future they are handy to have
  for (var i=1;i<dataA.length;i++) 
  {
    var emailAddress=dataA[i][1];  
    var message=formatRow(sheet.getName(),dataA[i],backA[i],dataA[0]);
    var subject="Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    //s+=br + '<strong>EmailAddress:</strong>' + emailAddress + br + '<strong>Subject:</strong>' + subject + br + message + '**************************************' + br;
    MailApp.sendEmail({to:emailAddress,subject:subject,htmlBody:message});

  }
  //var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Email Message')
}
```

I just noticed the yellow background so I quickly added another section for it.

```
   //assume Timestamp,EmailAddres,Score,FirstName,LastName,Section...
function formatRow(sheetName,rowA,rowbackA,titleA)
{
  var br='<br />';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var html='';
  if(rowA && rowbackA)
  {
    html='';
    for(var j=0;j<rowA.length;j++)
    {
      switch(rowbackA[j])
      {
        case '#ff0000':
          html+=br + '<span style="font-weight:600;font-size:20px;">' + titleA[j] + ':</span>' + br + '<span style="background-color:#ff0000;">' + rowA[j] + '</span>' + br;
          break;
        case '#ffff00':
          html+=br + '<span style="font-weight:600;font-size:20px;">' + titleA[j] + ':</span>' + br + '<span style="background-color:#ffff00;">' + rowA[j] + '</span>' + br;
          break;
        case '#ffffff':
          html+=br + '<span style="font-weight:600;font-size:20px;">' + titleA[j] + ':</span>' + br + '<span style="background-color:#ffffff;">' + rowA[j] + '</span>' + br;
          break
      }
    }
  }
  return html;
}
```

Just a reminder I'm using #ff0000 for red so don't change to a different shade without making a change to the code.

In the event that one student's email gets eaten by the dog, you might like to send just one email.

```
function sendOneEmail(firstName,lastName) 
{
  if(firstName && lastName)
  {
    var br='<br />';
    var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
    var dataRange=sheet.getDataRange();
    var dataA=dataRange.getValues();
    var backA=dataRange.getBackgrounds();
    //var s='';//Please leave the commented lines.  If needed for the future they are handy to have
    for (var i=1;i<dataA.length;i++) 
    {
      if(firstName==dataA[i][3] && lastName==dataA[i][4])
      {
        var emailAddress=dataA[i][1];  
        var message=formatRow(sheet.getName(),dataA[i],backA[i],dataA[0]);
        var subject="Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
        //s+=br + '<strong>EmailAddress:</strong>' + emailAddress + br + '<strong>Subject:</strong>' + subject + br + message + '**************************************' + br;
        MailApp.sendEmail({to:emailAddress,subject:subject,htmlBody:message});
       }
    }
    //var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
    //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Email Message')
  }
}
```

Here's a birds eye view of the Spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: I should have been more specific. The only formats I used were background color and text color (for comments). Are you saying I'd need to code each cell that I edited with html?

Comment: It would actually be easier just to build a little html template then insert the values like my little example with `Utilities.formatString('formatted String',list of parameters);` Then you would just add the variable into the list of parameters and they would populate all of the '%s'.  If your familar with the famous printf command it does the same thing.  Then that way all you have to do is build the html template.  It also makes filling out the spreadsheet a lot easier.  It's kind of a mail merge idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Here is a link to a copy with personal info removed. I literally want to make a carbon copy of each row and email it to the address that would be in column B. It is necessary that they see the red background (to know it's wrong) and the colored text (my comments).

https://docs.google.com/a/hcpsnc.org/spreadsheets/d/1UFN8k-Bm1uPCYRkUb2y4V6iu3z0-_Yr-R3MrXek3rmw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Should be now. Sorry.

Comment: By the way, I just noticed the yellow background what does it mean?

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot. 

(...and the yellow was just a visual marker for me to see the where the next period's answers began. I forgot to add that as a question.)

Comment: I appreciate it if you would checkoff my answer.